# Broadcaster & Listener

Tags: ros, broadcaster, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

May I know what is the difference between broadcaster/listener and tf broadcaster/listener?

Still new to ROS fuerte. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82466/broadcaster-&-listener/) by [FuerteNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/6786/fuertenewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2013-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The one is specific for tf messages and interprets them to easily access tf.

A non-tf broadcaster/listener is usually called publisher/subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2